# Keycloak display different text in theme

Tags: jboss, keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm customizing the keycloak theme but want to display a different text in the template.ftl based on the current page.

How can I achieve that in the freemarker template - template.ftl, something like this

```
<#if login>
   ...
</#if>
<#if register>
    ...
</#if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, figured it out...not a big deal to do

```
                    <#if register??>
                        <li><a href="${url.registrationUrl}">Sign In</a></li>                            
                    <#else>
                        <li><a href="${url.registrationUrl}">${msg("doRegister")}</a></li>
                    </#if>
```

Comment: Do you know what the key for login-reset-password.ftl is?